# Иконка календарь с помощью CSS3

Tags: css, css3

Есть такой вопрос. У меня иконка для календаря на сайте.

Хотел бы создать ту же самую иконку с помощью `css`.

На мой взгляд это возможно но пока что не получается сделать желаемое.

Вот сама иконка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну от тебя я не ожидал такого вопроса))))  Привет...  Сделай лучше на `svg`, хотя и на `css` 5ти минут  достаточно

Comment: @Air У всех могут быть проблемы, ну `svg` это последний вариант.

Comment: `svg` лучший вариант, он должен быть первым

Comment: @Air если это можно на `css` то это сейчас для меня приемлемо.

Comment: погоди щас сделаю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Глупо конечно велосипедить ... похоже ?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  padding-top: 34px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-line {
  background: #222;
  width: 40px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.top-line span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #666;
  transform: translate(0, -10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <div class="top-line">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо хороший вариант.

Comment: ну вот и есть))))))